# Git tags from Laravel app with git-flow

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, git-flow

I'm building a Laravel 4 app, I began this with the skeleton app which I had downloaded and I was tracking the upstream for the frequent updates [as per Niall O'Brien's instructions](http://niallobrien.me/2013/03/installing-and-updating-laravel-4/).

I've just started using git-flow on the project and I was testing my first feature branch and release. My release was tagged and pushed to my remote Unfuddle repository and its pushed my tag (0.01) but also appears to have pushed all the tags from the laravel skeleton app. What should I do here to remove the tags from local and remote - if indeed I should remove them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I began this with the skeleton app which I had downloaded and I was tracking the upstream for the frequent updates as per Niall O'Brien's instructions.

L4 is now stable and I think that skeleton app won't change a lot. IMO it's not necessary to fetch changes from upstream.

For my new project I decided to download the skeleton, not clone it from git repo.

> What should I do here to remove the tags from local and remote

You can simply use `git tag -d [tag]`. To remove it from remote do `git push origin :[tag]`.

> if indeed I should remove them?

It' up to You. For me it's quite o problem to have tags from framework. Number versions should be for project, not framework.

Comment: you think it makes sense to remove my upstream remote then? and then just remove the tags as you outline?

Comment: Yea, I think You can do that.